# Strange behavior of input element with position:relative at active pseudoclass in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

What is the reason of Firefox's strange behavior? If I add `position:relative` to css of the input pseudoclass definition it takes two clicks to open file dialog.

```
input {
    /* something */
}
input:active{
  position:relative;
}
```

Try to open the link in Firefox, the input do nothing on the first click but opens dialog on the second one.

https://jsfiddle.net/4Lgk5sou/

I used it to make effect of a pressed button: `position:relative; top:1px;`.

P.S. I fix it by moving `position:relative` into basic style of the input: `input{ ... }`.

Tested at Firefox 41.0.1

Comment: just delete your `input:active` class and its going to work.

Comment: Was wrong, `:active` is valid on `button`s too. W3C's selector cheatsheet needs updating haha. Anyways, you could always set `top:1px;` in the `:active` section and put the `position:relative;` in the `input` section. Fixes your issue. As for why.... Something to do with how FF is determining what you clicked is my guess, and the reposition causes it to hiccup on what exactly you clicked on.